# How could I generate a list of dates based on user input?

Tags: excel, pyxll

Say that I have a spreadsheet that allows users to put in some metadata like the following:

```
Date range start: mm/dd/yyyy
Date range end: mm/dd/yyyy
Mondays: (y/n)
Tuesdays: (y/n)
Wednesdays: (y/n)
Thursdays: (y/n)
Fridays: (y/n)
```

Based on that, I want to generate a list of dates in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy` that starts on `4/1/2019`, ends on `4/30/2019` and only includes dates of the day that was indicated with a `y`.

So if a user put in `start date = 04/01/2019`, `end date = 04/30/2019`, `y` for just Mondays and Wednesdays, the list would look like:

```
04/01/2019
04/03/2019
04/08/2019
04/10/2019
04/15/2019
04/17/2019
04/22/2019
04/24/2019
04/29/2019
```

Couldn't find an Excel function to start with. I don't know VBA but imagine it would be possible to do this with that.

If I wanted to write this in Python by using an add-in like `Pyxll`, would everyone with a copy of the Excel file be required to install `Pyxll`?

Comment: Easily achievable with `VBA`. Not sure if that's an option?

Comment: Not throwing VBA out the window just yet, but want to see what other options there are. I'd need to learn VBA so hopefully the learning curve isn't bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@simplycoding: VBA doesn't have a function or suroutine ready to do what you are looking for right out of the box. However, you can compose your own ones based on whatever VBA has on offer, which is a lot.

This is my startup scenario:

[image]

I wrote, tested and commented the following SUB in some 20 minutes. Believe me when I say I'm not a first row VBA coder.

```
Sub DateList()
'(C) Antonio Rodulfo, 2019
Dim dEnd, dStart, dCounter As Date
Dim iaDays(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim iCounter, iRow As Integer
'   Indent your sentences properly
    '   Reading parameters
    dStart = Cells(2, 1).Value
    dEnd = Cells(2, 2)
    For iCounter = 1 To 5
        If Cells(2, 2 + iCounter) = "y" Then
            iaDays(iCounter) = 1
        Else
            iaDays(iCounter) = 0
        End If
    Next iCounter
    '   Here's where the list of dates will start
    iRow = 4
    '   I process the dates: Excel stores dates in its own
    '       coding, which we can use to run a for..next loop
    For dCounter = dStart To dEnd
        '   Weekday(datecode,type) returns the day of week
        '   type 2 means the week starts with  monday being day 1
        iCounter = Weekday(dCounter, 2)
        '   The sub only sets dates for working days
        '   monday to friday
        If iCounter <= 5 Then
            '   date must be set if found "y" in the matching day
            If iaDays(iCounter) = 1 Then
                '   I like setting the proper numberformat so
                '   that no surprises are found when reading it
                Cells(iRow, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
                Cells(iRow, 1) = dCounter
                '   Increasing iRow sets the focus on next row
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    '   Adding the index name to the next sentence helps
    '   tracking the structures
    Next dCounter
End Sub
```

I always recommend using `Option Explicit` when coding. It can seem annoying at first, but it will help you a lot when testing and debugging your code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! I was able to tweak it to write across columns instead of rows and into another sheet. One small thing though, the script seems to write dates up to but not including the `End Date` parameter when it should be included. How should I go about editing the script to have that logic?

Answer (score 0):

I was challenged by your request to not use VBA at all, so I was playing around with some Excel functions and here's what I would like you to try.

I used your metadata in the following cells:

[image: metadata]

**OPTION 1 - easy**

Enter the following Array function into cell D1 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and drag it all the way to the right (e.g. up to cell AW1):

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(WEEKDAY($B$1+COLUMN()-4,2),--($B$3:$B$7="y")*(ROW($B$3:$B$7)-2),0)),($B$1+COLUMN()-4)<=$B$2),$B$1+COLUMN()-4,"")
```

All dates that are between Start & End dates and for the required weekdays are displayed. However, this option does not prevent the gaps, so you will have lots of blank columns in between.

**OPTION 2 - complete**

Enter the following Array function into cell D2 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and drag it all the way to the right:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(($B$1+ROW($B$1:$B$30)-1)*(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(WEEKDAY($B$1+ROW($B$1:$B$30)-1,2),(--($B$3:$B$7="y")*(ROW($B$3:$B$7)-2)),0)),1,0)),30-COUNT(MATCH(WEEKDAY($B$1+ROW($B$1:$B$30)-1,2),(--($B$3:$B$7="y")*(ROW($B$3:$B$7)-2)),0))+COLUMN()-3)),"")
```

As you can see, this option displays all "proper" dates next to each other, without any gaps.

Hope you will find this helpful - I had lots of fun playing around with the second option and I'm sure it can be still improved.

Take care,
Justyna